# check all input values of same class is empty jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here I have many input text fields with same class like

```
<input type="text" class="MyClass"></input>
<input type="text" class="MyClass"></input>
<input type="text" class="MyClass"></input>
```

My requirement is to check wheather all input fields of this class is empty or not. 
I've tried this

```
if(!('.MyClass').val()){
alert("empty");
}
```

But it doesn't make any result. Can anyone help?

Comment: @Mr_Green `$('.MyClass')` will return array of items...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can check

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var $nonempty = $('.MyClass').filter(function() {
    return this.value != ''
  });

  if ($nonempty.length == 0) {
    alert('empty')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="MyClass" />
<input type="text" class="MyClass" />
<input type="text" class="MyClass" />
<button>test</button>
```

Or using a flag

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var flag = false;
  $('.MyClass').filter(function() {
    if (this.value != '') {
      flag = true;
      //no need to iterate further
      return false;
    }
  });

  if (!flag) {
    alert('empty')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="MyClass" />
<input type="text" class="MyClass" />
<input type="text" class="MyClass" />
<button>test</button>
```

Comment: This only works for the first input field. If you put something in one of them and leave the rest empty, it still thinks they're all filled.

Comment: @Xander that is what the OP asked for -- a way to test whether all fields are empty, not a way to test whether all fields are filled in.

Comment: remove the $ sign from variables in the first method.

Answer (score 3):

You can compare the length of number of input with number of empty input using :

```
var allemptylength=$(".MyClass").filter(function() {
    return this.value.length !== 0;
})});

if($('.MyClass').length== allemptylength.length){
  alert("all empty");
}
```

### Working Demo

Comment: The `input` element can't have children so that will be always empty

Comment: It will not work, as `:empty` checks content of the element, not its value.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure each classes are checked, use

```
$.each($('.MyClass'),function() {
   if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
    alert('empty');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check it like this:

```
var isEmpty = !$('.MyClass').filter(function() {
    return this.value.trim();
}).length;
```

Also remove all `</input>` tags. input elements are self-closable.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    var hasNoValue;
    $('.MyClass').each(function(i) {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
              hasNoValue = true;
        }
    });
    if (hasNoValue) {
        alert('All have no value');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try   **is(':checked')**

```
$('.MyClass').each(function(){
    alert($(this).is(':checked');)
});
```

this will alert only the checked elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works for me

```
var flag = 1;
$(".MyClass").each(function(i){
    if ($(this).val() == "")
        flag++;
});
if (flag == 1)
    alert('all have values');
else
    alert('some or all doesn\'t have value');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').each(function(index,value){
    if($(this).val()!=''){
        $(this).addClass('success');
    }else{
        $(this).removeClass('someClass');
        $(this).addClass('warning');
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
        //do something else...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this . 100% working..

```
var emptyLength = $(".MyClass").filter(function() {
    return this.value == "";
}).length;
 if (emptyLength > 0)
{
    alert("Please enter all peramerter's value");
    return;
}
```

Thanks.