# Check all input values of same two class if NOT empty in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have already research about this but. I have two different `class` to check. How can I do that? [Please visit this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28494084/check-all-input-values-of-same-class-is-empty-jquery). Sir @Arun P Johny had the answer. But What if I have two or more `class` to check?

Like so...
`<input type="text" class="myClass[]">`
`<input type="text" class="myClass[]">`
`<input type="text" class="myClass[]">`
`<input type="text" class="myClass2[]">`
`<input type="text" class="myClass2[]">`

Comment: `myClass[]` array of class is not required you can just put `myClass` this work

Answer (score 2):

Use [Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/), Also as you are using meta-characters in the CSS class you have to escape them with `\\`

```
var elements = $('.myClass\\[\\],.myClass2\\[\\]').filter(function() {
    return this.value != ''
});
```

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var elements = $('.myClass\\[\\],.myClass2\\[\\]').filter(function() {
    return this.value != ''
  });

  if (elements.length == 0) {
    alert('empty')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="myClass[]">
<input type="text" class="myClass[]">
<input type="text" class="myClass[]">
<input type="text" class="myClass2[]">
<input type="text" class="myClass2[]">
<button type="button">test</button>
```

Comment: Can you provide a snippet or a jsFiddle?

Comment: Is this available for `<select>` elements?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `class^=myClass` as in the example below, or you can use `$(".myClass\\[\\], .myClass2\\[\\]")`

`class^=myClass` means that your class has to start with `myClass`

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var flag = false;
  $('input[class^=myClass]').filter(function() {
    if (this.value != '') {
      flag = true;
      //no need to iterate further
      return false;
    }
  });

  if (!flag) {
    alert('empty')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="myClass[]">
<input type="text" class="myClass[]">
<input type="text" class="myClass[]">
<input type="text" class="myClass2[]">
<input type="text" class="myClass2[]">
<button>test</button>
```

Comment: What if I change the classes? like 3 `class="exam[]"`, 2 `class="total_exam[]"`,  4`class="final_exam[]"`

Comment: Then i would do $('input[class*=exam\\[\\]]')

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if($( "input[class*='myClass']" ).val()==""){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `input` element contains only one class name as `myClass[]` or `myClass2[]` then you can use this

```
if($('input[class^="myClass"]').val()==""){}
```

But if you have some other classes for `input` like

```
<input type="text" class="testClass myClass[]">
```

then you need to use this

```
if($('input[class*="myClass"]').val()==""){}
```